# use debian without gui and still use software like firefox and open office

Tags: debian, command-line

i try to figure out about how to use linux from command line only.
if i boot debian (im using parrot atm) without gui, can i still use software like firefox and open office, or does it have to be "command-line-software" ?

Comment: You need a graphical window manager (simpler) or a graphical desktop environment (more advanced) in order to use programs with a graphical user interface. If you work locally, you need it there, if you connect via a network (e.g. ssh), you need it in the client computer, where you display the graphics.

Answer (score 2):

No, because Firefox and LibreOffice are written to work with a GUI.  They can open multiple different windows, and they rely on the GUI to support this.

But also yes, you can run them from a command line if you want - i.e. from a terminal program.  And you can set up a GUI in different ways, some of which have much less features.

A well-known option which does not have a panel is [OpenBox](https://wiki.debian.org/Openbox).  To start apps in OpenBox, you right click on the desktop, and use the menu it opens.  You can use this to start a terminal emulator, Firefox, LibreOffice - and most other GUI programs that you chose to install.

Note 1: Even when you select a well-known option, you might start to realize you want to add some more features :-).

Note 2: The instructions I linked should give you OpenBox running on top of X Windows.  By default, Gnome in Debian 10 uses a newer system instead, referred to as Wayland.  You might have reason to change to a Wayland-based system in future.  So you might want to avoid getting too deep into specific X Windows tricks.